# Edit file.php from controller using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, fopen, fwrite

I need to add some content to a file from a controller in CodeIgniter, in my local enviroment I do this and works fine:

```
$handle = fopen(APPPATH."config/file.php", "a+");
fwrite($handle, $stuff);

fclose($handle);
```

However the file doesn't seem to get altered when it runs in the production environment server.

At first I though it could be permission issues but *chmoding* 777 the directory doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb of me, I *chmoded* the folder containing the file but not the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me APPPATH is pointing to a different path. Make sure APPPATH is correct.